# Adding labels to a Bokeh plot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a data frame with columns with player names and their stats. I've plotting two different stats would like the player names to appear under each dot on the scatterplot.

This is what I have so far but it's not working. For text, I assume this is the list of names I want under each point on the plot and source is where the names are coming from.

```
p = Scatter(dt,x='off_rating',y='def_rating',title="Offensive vs. Defensive Eff",color="navy")
labels = LabelSet(x='off_rating',y='def_rating',text="player_name",source=dt)
p.add_layout(labels)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're on the right path. However, the `source` for `LabelSet` has to be a DataSource. Here is an example code.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.charts import Scatter
from bokeh.models import LabelSet
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

source = DataFrame(
    dict(
        off_rating=[66, 71, 72, 68, 58, 62],
        def_rating=[165, 189, 220, 141, 260, 174],
        names=['Mark', 'Amir', 'Matt', 'Greg', 'Owen', 'Juan']
    )
)


scatter_plot = Scatter(
                source,
                x='off_rating',
                y='def_rating',
                title='Offensive vs. Defensive Eff',
                color='navy')

labels = LabelSet(
            x='off_rating',
            y='def_rating',
            text='names',
            level='glyph',
            x_offset=5, 
            y_offset=5, 
            source=ColumnDataSource(source), 
            render_mode='canvas')

scatter_plot.add_layout(labels)

show(scatter_plot)
```

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: yeah that works. what if i wanted to add text inside the plot just in general, to annotate something?

Comment: Just for completeness in this example the label names are strings. I was jut trying to label with an array of integers and it removed everything: legend label, title figure, toolbar... you name it. If you pass an array of int do not forget str().

Answer (score 3):

Solution by @Oluwafem is not working, as `bokeh.charts` is deprecated. Here is an updated solution

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show,ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import  ColumnDataSource,Range1d, LabelSet, Label

from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
source = DataFrame(
    dict(
        off_rating=[66, 71, 72, 68, 58, 62],
        def_rating=[165, 189, 220, 141, 260, 174],
        names=['Mark', 'Amir', 'Matt', 'Greg', 'Owen', 'Juan']
    )
)
p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=450, title = "'Offensive vs. Defensive Eff'")
p.circle('off_rating','def_rating',source=source,fill_alpha=0.6,size=10, )
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'off_rating'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'def_rating'
labels = LabelSet(x='off_rating', y='def_rating', text='names',text_font_size='9pt',
              x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=ColumnDataSource(source), render_mode='canvas')
p.add_layout(labels)
show(p)
```

[image]